# Implement unread messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am implementing a live chat.

Here is my server file.

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('userConnect', async (room, user_id) => {
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on('send-chat-message', (room, sender_id, userMessage) => {
        const message = new Message(room, sender_id, userMessage);
        db.query(message.saveMessage());
        socket.to(room).emit('chat-message', { message: userMessage, user: sender_id });
    });
});
```

This is how I implemented the connection to the room and the connection for sending messages from the client.

How can I make a function that the user has not yet read the message?

Comment: Did you happen to tried anything so far? Maybe you should do some more research over the internet and then post any specific query here.

Comment: @harry-joy I did not find a clear example to parse it. I would be grateful if you offer

Comment: You have to catch on client that user has / has not read the message. And add this with object that emits, for example `{ message: userMessage, user: sender_id, status: null | "received" | "read" }`. Where `null` is default value. This is one of the solutions of many.

Comment: @MegaRoks Read this article. It covers everything required to build a chat system including data modeling and message syncing.[link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-a-serverless-real-time-chat-application-with-aws-appsync)